# Let $G=\langle a\rangle$ and $G'=\langle b\rangle$ of order 12 and 4. Prove that there is a onto homomorphism with $o(Ker~ \phi)=3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G=\langle a\rangle$ and $G'=\langle b\rangle$ be two cyclic groups of order 12 and 4 respectively. Prove that there exists a onto homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow G'$ with $o(Ker~ \phi)=3$.

Attempt:

$G=\{e_G, a, a^2, \cdots a^{11}\}$ and $o(a)=12=o(G)$

$G'=\{e_{G'}, b, b^2, b^{3}\}$ and $o(b)=4=o(G')$

Clearly, as $4|12$, there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of order 3 generated by $a^m$ where  $m=12/3=4$.

Isomorphism theorem gives $G/{Ker~ \phi}\simeq G'$ if $\phi$ is an **onto** homomorphism. Then

1. How to prove that $\phi$ is an **onto** homomorphism?
2. How to show $o(Ker~ \phi)=3$

Please help me in an elaborate form so that I can understand. Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

If  $\phi$ is an **onto** homomorphism then I can find $o(Ker~ \phi)$ as follows

I can apply Isomorphism Theorem  $G/{Ker~ \phi}\simeq G'$ then $o( G/{Ker~ \phi})=o( G')$ i.e $$\frac{o( G)}{o({Ker~ \phi})}=o(G')$$ that is $$\frac{12}{o({Ker~ \phi})}=4$$ that is $$o({Ker~ \phi})=12/4=3.$$

How to solve 1st part. Please help.

**Edit 2:**

How to show that it is Onto Homomorphism for this particular problem?

If $e$ and $e′$ are the identity elements of $G$ and $G′$ respectively.

For any $x\in G$
then 
$ϕ(x)=ϕ(ex)=ϕ(e+e+⋯+e)=ϕ(e)+ϕ(e)+⋯+ϕ(e)=xϕ(e)$. Then $ϕ$ is completly known if $ϕ(e)$ is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\phi(a^n) = b^n$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z$. Let us show that this is a morphism.

If $g = a^m \in G$ and $h = a^n \in G$, then

$$\phi (gh) = \phi (a^m a^n) = \phi (a^{m+n}) = b^{m+n} = b^m b^n = \phi (a^m) \phi (a^n) = \phi (g) \phi (h) .$$

If $g = a^m$, then

$$\phi (g^{-1}) = \phi ((a^m)^{-1}) = \phi (a^{-m}) = b^{-m} = (b^m)^{-1} = \phi (g) ^{-1} .$$

Finally, letting $n=0$ in the definition, we get

$$\phi (e) = \phi (a^0) = b^0 = e' .$$

Thus, $\phi$ is a group morphism.

Notice now that if $a^m \in \ker \phi$, then $b^m = e'$ and since $b$ is a generator of $G'$, it follows that $\text{ord } b \mid m$, which means $4 \mid m$. Conversely, if $m = 4k$, then $\phi (a^m) = \phi (a^{4k}) = b^{4k} = (b^4)^k = e' ^k = e'$. This shows that $\ker \phi = \{ a^{4k} \mid k \in \Bbb Z \} = \{e, a^4, a^8\}$ (because $a^{12} = e$), which is a subgroup with three elements, hence of order $3$.

---

To show that $\phi$ is onto, use the fundamental isomorphism theorem and compare the cardinals:

$$\left| \frac {G} {\ker \phi} \right| = |\phi (G')| ,$$

and by Lagrange's theorem the left-hand side is just $\dfrac {12} 3 = 4$, which is just $|G'|$, whence it follows that $\phi (G) = G'$, so $\phi$ is onto.

Alternatively (and more explicitly), if $b^n \in G'$ and $n = 4q + r$ with $r \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, then

$$\phi ( a ^r) = b^r = e' b^r = (b^4)^q b^r = b^{4q + r} = b^n ,$$

so $\phi$ is onto.

---

Honestly, the whole proof is a bit long when done with all the details as above. The idea, though, is easy: define $\phi(a) = b$ (i.e. send the generator of $G$ to the generator of $G'$) and extend this by multiplication.

Comment: What do you mean by  group morphism? Is it  group homomorphism

Comment: @rama_ran: Yes, exactly, that's another (but shorter) name. You will also encounter it when speaking about rings, algebras and other algebraic structures.

Comment: Is not **sufficient** to show $\phi(gh)=\phi(g)\phi(h)$?

Comment: @rama_ran: No, that would only be a [semigroup morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#Homomorphisms_and_congruences) between $G$ and $G'$ (with their respective underlying semigroup structures obtained from their group structures).

Comment: Thanks. In books I read homomorphism condition as $\phi(gh)=\phi(g)\phi(h)$ only. Anyway, I shall read again. I understand your 1st method. Would you please elaborate the alternative method you have mentioned at your suitable time.

Comment: @rama_ran: Well, isn't it elaborate enough? To me, it contains all the needed details. What part exactly don't you follow?

Comment: Yes I understand. But you have written "Honestly, the whole proof is a bit long ......." what exactly you want to tell. I think you have done all. What is left?

Comment: @rama_ran: Nothing is left. That concluding remark was for you to keep in mind that the single essential fact of the whole proof is $\phi (a) = b$. Once you have this, the rest of it comes naturally. So don't force yourself to memorize the whole proof - that single formula contains it all. This is what that last line says.

Comment: @AlexM. I'm sorry, but **of course it is sufficient** to show that $\phi(gh) = \phi(g)\phi(h)$. A semigroup homomorphism between groups is already a *group* homomorphism: $\phi(e) = \phi(ee) = \phi(e)\phi(e)$ so $e' = \phi(e)$ by cancellation, and $\phi(a^{-1}) = \phi(a^{-1})\phi(a)\phi(a)^{-1} = \phi(a^{-1}a)\phi(a)^{-1} = \phi(e)\phi(a)^{-1} = e'\phi(a)^{-1} = \phi(a)^{-1}$.

Comment: @Unit: Ha! I've been familiar with groups for so long, and yet I've never thought about this! Good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what should $\phi(a)$ be?

Comment: $\phi(a)=\phi (ea)=\phi(e+e+\cdots +e)=\phi(e)+\phi(e)+\cdots+\phi(e)=ae'$ where $e$ and $e'=\phi(e)$ are the identity elements of $G$ and $G'$